# Regex Random character VB.Net

Tags: html, regex, vb.net

So, this is my code:

```
    Dim sourceString As String = New System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString("www.example.com")
    TextBox2.Text = sourceString
    Dim findtext2 As String = "(?<=<div class=""books"">)(.*?)(?=</div>)"
    Dim myregex2 As String = TextBox2.Text
    Dim doregex2 As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(myregex2, findtext2)
    Dim matches2 As String = ""
    For Each match2 As Match In doregex2
        matches2 = matches2 + match2.ToString + Environment.NewLine
    Next
    MsgBox(matches2)
```

It's getting all values between `<div class="books">` and `</div>`, but there is one big problem.

After "books", there are 3 characters (like `<div class="books672">`).

On example.com, the HTML is like this:

```
<div class="books321">Book1</div>
<div class="books785">Book2</div>
<div class="books547">Book3</div>
<div class="books182">Book4</div>
<div class="books317">Book5</div>
<div class="books970">Book6</div>
```

How could i get "Book1, Book2..."? Does something for random characters exist in regex?

Comment: you can use `(?<=<div class="books\w{3}">)(.*?)(?=</div>)`

Comment: and yes, don't parse HTML with regex

Comment: [Obligatory link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/5240004) Do yourself a favor and use an HTML parsing library.

Comment: Thanks, works perfect!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By adding `\w{1}` it recognizes it as one random character. In this case, i needed 3 random characters, so the solution would be:

```
(?<=<div class="books\w{3}">)(.*?)(?=</div>)
```